# Unfortunately My app has stopped [Android Emulator]

Tags: android, android-emulator

While I am adding an Action bar, emulator will be displayed "Unfortunately MainActivity has stopped", even no error and installed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.trintwo"     
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion = "7"
        android:targetSdkVersion = "18" />

    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:theme="@style/Theme.Holo.Light">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name = "com.example.trintwo.DisplayMessageActivity"
                android:label = "@string/title_activity_display_message"
                android:parentActivityName = "com.example.trintwo.MainActivity">
                <meta-data
                        android:name = "android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                        android:value = "com.example.trintwo.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

This is my res/values/styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
    res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
-->
        <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light"></style>
        <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
                 parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">

        </style>

</resources>
```

debug successfully
and installed successfully
but
emulator show this "Unfortunately MainActivity has stopped"

I am using terminal [not eclipse]

Comment: Exception logcat, please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be missing the  attribute from your manifest. This could be your problem. For more information, see here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Comment: please tell exactly. which attribute will add?

Comment: That depends entirely on what version of Android you are compiling for. Please read the link I gave you, it will tell you exactly what you need to know.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you added the `CustomActionBarTheme` style to your `styles.xml` file (per your code sample) then there's nothing wrong with that markup.

Can you provide the markup that is using the `CustomActionBarTheme` style?

Also, if you remove that style altogether does the app run? Always a good idea to reverse changes until you get back to a working version then line-by-line add the potentially offending code back in.

Comment: same error even I use only androidManifest.xml im not using style.xml file

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

> Unfortunately MainActivity has stopped

There is only one reason for that. You got an EXCEPTION. You need to install [logcat](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html) some how. It will tell you what it is.

Show us the log exception and we will help you.

Comment: if i give $ adb logcat, it will give 1000 line. which command will i use for excatly show exception?

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(  995): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(  995): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable. and i already installd android support library. Also android-support-v7-appcompat.jar file in android/support/v7/appcompat

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem while going through a tutorial.

What seemed to worked for me is cleaning my project in Eclipse and running my app on my device again.

Answer (score 0):

there is no

```
<uses-sdk>
```

tag at your manifest please show this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html)
and this to add your SDKs [Link2](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

Answer (score 0):

Are you building the app for the correct API Level?

If your API level is below 11 you need to import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar

Otherwise import android.app.ActionBar

Comment: You can try and install Acra so that you get the logs leading up to the exception